# How to write weak form for a von Karman equation with Airy stress function?

Tags: integration, classical-mechanics, finite-element-method

I have Föppl–von-Karman plate equation:

$$
\Delta^2 w - (w_{xx} \varphi_{yy} + w_{yy} \varphi_{xx}-2w_{xy} \varphi_{xy}) = f\\
\Delta^2 \varphi + (w_{xx}w_{yy}-w_{xy}^2) = 0
$$

How do I write this equation in a weak form (suitable for FEM calculation)? I know how to integrate by parts $\nabla^2$ and $\Delta^2$ operators, but what should I do with von Karman bracket $[u, v]=u_{xx} v_{yy} + u_{yy} v_{xx}-2u_{xy} v_{xy}$?

Comment: What are the domain and boundary conditions (BC)?  (Typically, the weak form will depend upon these, in particular the BC.)